# Missing backslash symbol as with the right curly bracket however the thing works as with the left curly bracket of json file in snippet

Tags: json, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

If the body of the snippet of a json file is

```
"\\left\\{"
```

then the return value of it is \left\{

And if the another body is

```
"\\right\\}"
```

then the return value of it is **\right}**

I want **\right\}** as the return value.

How do I implement it?

Comment: This will give you what you want : `\\right\\\\}`  But why what you had doesn't work?... Adding a space makes this work: `\\right\\ }` I think there is a regex bug in the snippet engine.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
"\\right\\\\}"
```

instead of

```
"\\right\\}"
```

to get the return value of **\right}**